# errno, strerror and Linux system calls

Tags: c, linux, error-handling, errno

I can use `strerror()` to get text representation of **errno** value after using CRT functions, like `fopen()`. If I use `open()` Linux system call instead of CRT function, it also sets **errno** value when it fails. Is this correct to apply `strerror()` to this **errno** value? If not, is there some Linux system call, which does the same as `strerror()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

Yes

In  there is `perror`

```
if (-1 == open(....))
{
    perror("Could not open input file");
    exit(255)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and your code might be something like (untested) this:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <string.h>               // declares: char *strerror(int errnum);

   FILE *
   my_fopen ( char *path_to_file, char *mode ) {
     FILE *fp;
     char *errmsg;
     if ( fp = fopen( path_to_file, mode )) {
       errmsg = strerror( errno );  // fopen( ) failed, fp is set to NULL
       printf( "%s %s\n", errmsg, path_to_file );
     } 
     else {                         // fopen( ) succeeded
     ...
     } 

     return fp;                     // return NULL (failed) or open file * on success
   }
```

Comment: There is no use for the `errmsg` temp variable. Just put `strerror(errno)` directly in the argument list for `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Linux system calls are encapsulated by C library routines. `open()` system call is actually a function defined in the C library which calls the actual `open()` system call of the kernel.

**errno** is a variable defined and managed by the C library, not by the kernel. It is set upon the return of the system call with the error code returned by the kernel.

As an example, in the GNU C library, `open()` is defined in *sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open.c* as:

```c
int
__libc_open (const char *file, int oflag, ...)
{
  int mode = 0;

  if (__OPEN_NEEDS_MODE (oflag))
    {
      va_list arg;
      va_start (arg, oflag);
      mode = va_arg (arg, int);
      va_end (arg);
    }

  return SYSCALL_CANCEL (openat, AT_FDCWD, file, oflag, mode);
}
libc_hidden_def (__libc_open)

weak_alias (__libc_open, __open)
libc_hidden_weak (__open)
weak_alias (__libc_open, open)
```

The bottom macros establish a equivalence between *__libc_open()* and *open()*.
The *SYSCALL_CANCEL()* macros invokes the actual system call (which is `openat()`) and sets **errno** with the error code if any error condition occured.