# How to know if there is an error when attempting to open a file (when using fopen in C)

Tags: c, file, for-loop, fopen

I am opening multiple files in a while loop using fopen in C and want to be able to check if any of them will return an error. Relevant code:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<10; i++) { 
  file=fopen(myList[i], "r");
}
```

How will I know if the file I'm currently looking at will have an error when I attempt to open it or while I am reading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man fopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen):

> **Return Value**
>
> Upon successful completion `fopen()`, `fdopen()` and `freopen()` return a `FILE` pointer. Otherwise, `NULL` is returned and `errno` is set to indicate the error.

You can read more about `errno` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16507816/641451) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5685973/641451) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503878/641451)