# How to tell if opening input file failed in C

Tags: c, file-io, error-handling

#### Motivation

If I am sure that a given input file exists, I would like to loop until creation of a "file stream" for the file does not fail.

#### Question

I understand that with the following check we can tell if opening an input failed (and therefore, said file exists locally) in C,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *rec_in_file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    // If file cannot be opened, report error and exit
    if (rec_in_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but how can I tell if the file exists but something went wrong while creating the "file stream"? In preliminary research for the question, I could file no such mention of handling this case.

Comment: `errno` should be set according to the error `fopen()` encountered. An easy way to use this is to `perror()` after the `if (!rec_in_file)`.

Comment: ^ You should post this as answer EOF.

Comment: It's very unlikely that something would go wrong while creating the file stream. `fopen` failure is almost always due to a problem with the file, either it doesn't exist or you don't have correct permissions. `errno` should clarify.

Comment: @ronakg: There's already a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5685973/3185968

Comment: @Barmar - most modern systems allow files to be protected.   This can cause opening a file to fail, even if it exists.   A file that is protected to prevent read access cannot be opened for reading.   A file that is protected to prevent write access might (or might not) be able to be opened for reading, but not for writing.    Unfortunately, in standard C, there is no way to resolve such things.

Comment: @Peter That's what I meant by "you don't have correct permissions".

Comment: @Barmar: Since stdio is buffered, `fopen()` can also fail if it is unable to allocate memory for the buffer.

Comment: @Barma - my point is that your claim that it is "very unlikely that something would go wrong when creating the file stream" is false.

Comment: I interpreted that to mean that the problem is in the C runtime library, not an issue with the file itself.

Comment: @Barmar What I meant was a system-level failure (permissions or otherwise).

Comment: @ronakg: Assuming what Peter answered below is valid, the question you linked may "overlap", but it doesn't answer my question (again, assuming Peter's answer is correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking `errno` or a call of `perror()` can be used to get information after the `fopen()` fails.  The problem with that is that these means are not required to produce any information related to I/O errors.    Implementations often do, but they are not required to, and the information varies.

Generally speaking, you will need to use functions outside standard C, such as `access()` or `stat()` (supported by most Unix libraries), `PathFileExists()` (Windows API), or some other means provided by the host system.

Answer (score 4):

The `fopen` function may, but might not, set `errno` to indicate the specific cause of failure. If it doesn't, then the cause is likely not detectable, or you're dealing with a very poor implementation of the standard library.

> Why wouldn't the implementor of `fopen` not set `errno`, the standard C error-cause-reporting mechanism, unless for some reason it were difficult, or couldn't be done at all? If `fopen` *can* determine a specific cause for why the file cannot be opened, it's as simple matter to set `errno` to some value. If this is so hard that the C library implementor ducks out of it, it's probably not going to be easy for you, either, on that platform.

Because `fopen` might not set `errno` (ISO C doesn't require it), this creates an ambiguity: if `fopen` fails, and `errno` is nonzero, we don't know whether `fopen` set that value, or whether it was already nonzero.  The solution is: **assign zero to errno before trying fopen**.

Tip: if you're working in an older dialect of C, or in a style which avoids mixed declarations and statements, you can still do this with a comma expression:

```
FILE *f = (errno = 0, fopen(...));
```

the value and type of the comma expression is that of the right operand.

Then, in the case that `fopen` fails, test whether `errno` has changed to nonzero. If so, it probably contains information pertaining to the `fopen`. You can make an error message more informative, or take some special actions:

```
if (fp == NULL) {
    if (errno != 0)
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file, for this reason: %s\n!",
              strerror(errno));
    else
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file, for some reason.\n");
}
```

Tip: you can use `#ifdef` to see whether specific `errno` constants exist. For instance if you want to check for and do something special for the POSIX `EPERM`, wrap that code with `#ifdef EPERM ... #endif`.

Note that the above `errno` approach works fine on Microsoft Windows using the MSVCRT (Microsoft Visual C Run Time) C library (no Unix emulation layer).  Microsoft's `fopen` nicely sets `errno` to 2, and the `strerror` string for that is `"No such file or directory"`.  This 2 corresponds to the `ENOENT` constant, which Microsoft provides. `EPERM` is there and has value 1. The behavior of setting `errno` is documented; the following quote is straight out of MSDN: *"[i]f an error occurs, the global variable errno is set and may be used to obtain specific error information."*

Microsoft's `fopen` will also fail and set `errno` to `EINVAL` if you pass it null strings, and the invalid parameter handler is configured to allow execution to proceed.